# How do I output information in pre-request script

Tags: postman

Using the standalone version of Postman, how do I output some debug information in Postman pre-request script?

The code below works great for tests (post-request) but not for pre-request since there is no tests[] array.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["key = " + jsonData.key] = true;              // debug message
tests["value = " + jsonData.value] = true;          // debug message
```

Answer (score 41):

The only way I could find to accomplish this is by using:

```
console.log("key = " + key);
console.log("value = " + value);
```

And then open up the Postman console (Cmd + Option + C / Ctrl + Alt + C) to view the debugs logs in a different window.

Comment: Postman Console also includes the whole response, you just have to expand some entries to find it. That can sometimes have a root cause error message in it.